# Executing an Excel macro from Python

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

I have created a macro in excel with shortcut key as a <kbd>CTRL+l</kbd>. I want to run this macro using python3.3

Can someone help me here? This is what I managed so far:

```
import win32com.client as win32
 xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
 xl.Visible = 1
 xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Python33\mac.xlsm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this with EnsureDispatch, but here's how you do it with Dispatch

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xlApp = Dispatch('Excel.Application')

result = xlApp.Run("<macro name here>",<the macro variables go here -seperate each one with a comma>) 
# for example:
#result = xlApp.Run("myMacro", "foo","bar")

#and make sure you close the xl
xlApp.Quit()
```

oh and I'm aslo on python 2.7, (but I doubt it will matter as the dependency is win32)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to apply an example for Python 3.3. Got the result just by adding Application!

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch 
xlApp = Dispatch('Excel.Application') 
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Python33\mac.xlsm")
result = xlApp.Application.Run("<macro name here>",<the macro variables go here -seperate each one with a command>)
```